# How to synchronize tables in Django?

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-forms

In my database I want to synchronize two tables. I use auth_user(Default table provided by Django) table for registration and there was another table user-profile that contain entities username, email, age etc. How to autometically upadate the columns username and email in user-profile according to updation in auth_user table.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email  = models.EmailField()
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    auth_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: See the django signals documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: Do you have a possibility to reorganize your model's structure? Because you should better just use ForeignKey on `User` model and extract username simply by `profile.user.username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either modify the django registration code and include the code to save into your profile model on every new registration.

Or

You can set a signal on every save of User model. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save).

```
def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["created"]:
        p = Profile(user=kwargs["instance"], ...)
        p.save()
django.db.models.signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

create_profile() will be called every time any User object is saved.
In this example, I create Profile object only if a new User instance has been created. You can modify it to change existing Profile objects on every change in User instance, also.

Comment: Thank you..  Any alternate methods to do same thing(eg : using foreign-key)? If we do using this method then what is the use of   foreign-key?

Comment: @mridul Using Foreign key will enable you to link two entries of two different models with each other. But it will not ensure that Profile object is created when a new user registers.